# Installing 21.04 on Gigabyte B560M DS3H with Intel Core i9 - Multiple problems

Tags: uefi, intel, gigabyte

I have a brand new machine comprising

- Motherboard: Gigabyte B560M DS3H
- Processor: Intel Core i9-11900 2.5GHz (Rocket Lake)

After quite some troubleshooting I have managed to install Ubuntu 21.04 on this machine but I still have some problems. Skip to the end for the unresolved questions.

In order to get Ubuntu installed and booting I had to take the following unusual steps:

- To avoid power-off during boot I had to add kernel parameter: `acpi=off`. Without that parameter boot fails with message `Failed to look up EFI memory descriptor for 0x...`. If I use `acpi=ht` there is an abrupt hard reset during boot.
- The Ubuntu installer failed at the setting up GRUB stage. I was able to manually install grub using the chroot method [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Installing) except that a) I had to mount my boot partition at `/target/boot/efi` not `/target/boot` and b) I had to use the `--no-nvram` option of `grub-install` to avoid an `Operation not permitted` error.
- To get the onboard graphics working above 1024x768 resolution I had to `apt install linux-oem-20.04`

Now I can boot the OS but I have two unsolved problems:

1. According to `/proc/cpuinfo` the OS is only aware of one of my eight CPU cores.
2. The machine cannot power itself off, I can only power off via a long press on the physical power button.

Does anyone have any idea how to diagnose or fix these problems?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Do you have a most recent BIOS for the motherboard? My experience is more with ASUS motherboards, but they typically need a BIOS update out of the box.

Comment: I now have the latest BIOS version. Boots fine with `acpi=off` but doesnt find all my cores. Without that it powers off part way through boot.

Comment: Have you installed firmware-linux-nonfree? I added non-free to the repositories and now acpi works too.

Comment: There are many acpi choices, try acpi=ht for instance. Google for the list, like in: https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/kernel_administration_guide/listing_of_kernel_parameters_and_values